# Changing Canvas Fill inside Application

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to spawn a thread, which periodically changes the color of my oval canvas, but somehow this codes does nothing:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def laufer(self):
        self.canvas1.configure(fill='black')

    def bt_start(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.laufer)
        t.start()

    def createWidgets(self):    
        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self, width=50, height=50)
        self.canvas1.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50, outline="black", 
            fill="green", width=1)
        self.canvas1.grid(row=3, column=0)
    [bt_start...]
```

Which is the correct way to change the fill color?

Comment: Is this your real problem, or just an example _like_ your real problem? If you're merely wanting to update a canvas periodically you don't need threads.

Comment: The Problem is that the canvas fill color doesn't change as expected. And I have to use a Thread, because that's a exercise from our teacher.

Comment: Do you want to change the fill color of the oval or the background color of the canvas? `fill` is not a valid option for a Canvas widget.

Comment: I want to change the fill of the oval.
Which would be the right option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question about how to change the color of the item, you must use the [itemconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) method, giving it the id of the object you want to configure, or a tag that represents zero or more objects to configure.

For example:

```
self.id = self.canvas1.create_oval(..., fill="green")
...
self.canvas1.itemconfigure(self.id, fill="black")
```

There are bigger problems, however. You cannot interact with the canvas from any thread other than the main thread. It *might* work, but there's a good chance your app will eventually crash.

There are two solutions: the preferred one is, don't use threads. They add complexity, and a lot of times you just don't need them. In the type of program used in the question, threads are completely unnecessary.

If, however, you really do need threads for your program, the generally accepted solution is to create a thread-safe queue, have your worker threads post some kind of data to the queue, and then have your main thread poll the queue on a regular schedule to act upon the data.

Comment: Is there any other way to communicate with the main application thread  except the queue?

Comment: Since threads share variables, it is possible to call `itemconfig` from the new thread, but race conditions are always a problem in this kind of situations. I think that for teaching purposes this isn't a good assignment to be solved with threading. (PS: Sorry for the previous comment, I wrongly submitted before finishing it).

Comment: My teacher says queues are the way to solve this problem on microcontrollers. His example was written in C# an there it's also not possible to interact with control elements, but it calls 'report_progress', which calls a interupt in the main thread called 'report_changed', which then changes the control. ^^
Is there a similar way to call an function inside the main thread from my thread?

Comment: @WhatIsName: you can can any function from any thread, if you know what you are doing and your function is "thread safe". Tkinter functions are not thread safe so you have to do something else. As I said in my answer, typically your worker thread will push something onto a thread-safe queue, and your main thread will poll that queue.